# How to add onclick to simple js image loop

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, gallery

I have added buttons to a looping gallery but am not sure how to implement them so that clicking one will jump to the corresponding image? Please see jSfiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/NkryH/9/

Best regards,
Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if that's an option for you but you could consider a slideshow plugin like [SlideJS](http://slidesjs.com/)

Comment: Thanks guys but really need an edit for this javascript provided. Please kindly see: http://jsfiddle.net/NkryH/9/ Ta

Answer (score 1):

See this blog post of mine http://mycodelove.wordpress.com/2011/09/18/simple-photo-gallery-from-img-in-li/ u can modify it to suit your needs